# How to change DataTable type?

Tags: c#, datatable, type-conversion, decimal

How to clone the `DataTable` and change its column and row type to `decimal`?

```
private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
{
    DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
    using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
    {
        csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
        csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
        foreach (string column in colFields)
        {
            DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
            datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
            csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
            ;
        }
        while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
            //Making empty value as null
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fieldData[i] == "")
                {
                    fieldData[i] = null;
                }
            }
            csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
        }
    }

    return csvData;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the strings to `decimal` using [`decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use the correct column-type. Then you can use the [`DataRow.SetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360652%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extensions which support nullable types:

```
foreach (string column in colFields)
{
    DataColumn datacolumn = new DataColumn(column, typeof(decimal));
    datacolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
    csvData.Columns.Add(datacolumn);
}
while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
{
    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
    DataRow addedRow = csvData.Rows.Add();
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
    {
        decimal value;
        if(decimal.TryParse(fieldData[i].Trim(), out value))
            addedRow.SetField<decimal?>(i, value);
        else
            addedRow.SetField<decimal?>(i, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the DataColumn constructor that allows a type parameter.

```
public DataColumn(
    string columnName,
    Type dataType
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/x1tyd60z(v=vs.110).aspx

So, if every column is going to be of decimal type

```
foreach (string column in colFields)
    {
        DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column, typeof(decimal));
        datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
        csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
    }
```

Comment: when I use this an ArgumentException was unhandled  csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);Input string was not in correct format

Comment: Of course, you need to convert the value from csv file to decimal before adding it to the column, as you declared this column to contains decimal values. Either use decimal.Parse(fieldData) or Convert.ToDecimal(fieldData). csvData.Rows.Add(decimal.Parse(fieldData))

Comment: I am comparing table1 and table 2(string type) and then building a new table which I need to sort(table3).can I build table3 rows as decimal(there are -ve values I need it to convert to decimal so it considers -ve sign)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify data type when creating DataColumn. If you don't specify data type explicitly (like in your example) the column will be of type string:

```
DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column, typeof(Decimal));
```